# d3: multiple lines same graph with varying y domains?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graphing

I have data which is all time series, so the x axis of my d3 graph is always time. I need to support having multiple lines on one graph, but the different lines can have vastly different domains for the y axis data. For example line 1 can be

```
1    2     3     4     5     for times 1-5
5000 10000 15000 20000 25000 for times 1-5
```

What is a good way to try to handle this in d3?

Answer (score 3):

You could have two separate Y axes. One on the left hand side of the graph and one on the right.

This post describes setting up a two line graph. http://www.d3noob.org/2013/01/adding-more-than-one-line-to-graph-in.html

And this post describes setting two different y axes for the lines with a similar scale problem to the one you describe. http://www.d3noob.org/2013/01/using-multiple-axes-for-d3js-graph.html

The end result is something like this.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a [log scale](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales#wiki-log) if you don't have zeros for the y values. In any case, simply create a single y scale that ranges from the minimum to the maximum of all lines and use that for everything.

Comment: Thanks Lars. 0s are guaranteed to be in this data set at any time, so log scale won't work. I've considered the single y scale with min/max, but even so, my example would have a near incomprehensibly small line for 1,2,3,4,5.

Comment: You could add a very small value (0.001 or something like that) to get rid of the zeros and be able to use the log scale. You could then label this very small value as quasi-zero.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered stacking two plots on identical x-axis scales? Or for a rapid comparison, I sometimes re-scale one data series to bring it into the domain of the other, then note it in the legend. "series 1 (x10 scaling)"